# Copy html fields in email body without php

Tags: javascript, html, email

I need to copy my html form fields in email body. I am able to set other fields.

SEND EMAIL CODE :

```
<a href="mailto:karandeep.singh@abc.com?subject=Feedback/Suggestion&bcc=karandeep.singh@abc.com"> Send an Email </a>
```

FORM CODE :

```
<li><input type="text" name="incident" class="field-style field-full align-none"  placeholder="Incident Number" maxlength="10"/>
</li>
```

I want this input field to be copied to body and in subject of the email too, but user has to click on send and it should only on html or javascript . 
If possible. 
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: not sure what you want coppied exactly, do you want the value of the input field ?

Comment: YES what ever will be the value in that input field , I want that in email's body .

Answer (score 0):

Done it with only html and javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/Damian239/fuog3e3L/1/

HTML:

```
<a id="send-button" href="#">Send</a>
<textarea id="description"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var href = "mailto:joedoe@gmail.com";

document.getElementById('description').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var body = this.value;
    if((body !== "") && (typeof body !== "undefined")) {
        document.getElementById('send-button').href = href + '?body=' + body;   
    } else {
      document.getElementById('send-button').href = "#";
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes this is working but you used just one text are , I have various input fields which I need to pick like following . 
I am new so not able to get how to pick these 

<li>
    <input type="text" name="summary" class="field-style field-full align-none"  placeholder="Summary"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="text" name="pname" class="field-style field-split align-left"  placeholder="Primary Contact Name"/>
 <input type="text" name="pnum1" class="field-style field-split align-right" maxlength="12" placeholder="Primary Contact Number"/>
</li>

Comment: i dont know about contact names and numbers but you can add any part of the email as an input as this: <input type='text' name='bcc'/>, <input type='text' name='cc'/> e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

In your HTML:

```
<a onclick="setMailTo(this)"> Send an Email </a>


<li><input type="text" id="incidentNum" name="incident" class="field-style field-full align-none"  placeholder="Incident Number" maxlength="10"/>
</li>
```

In you Javascript:

```
function setMailTo(link){
   var incidentNum = document.getElementById("incidentNum").value;
   var href = "mailto:karandeep.singh@abc.com?";
   href += "subject=Feedback/Suggestion for incident:" + incidentNum; //Or anything else you want
   href += "&body=suggestion regarding incident:" + incidentNum; //This will set the body content
   href += "&bcc=karandeep.singh@abc.com";

   link.href = href;
}
```